# How do I edit what apple mail shows as email summary in my script?

Tags: editor

First off, I'm a bad coder, and a mediocre engineer, so excuse my dumb questions. Also this is sort of fringe stuff so not sure anyone would know the answers anyways. I wrote this script years ago to automate sending emails and to have them sent from my account, at a slow enough pace to not trip email blockers at companies that I send hundreds of emails to at once. Over the years and updates of Mac Os, the way my script operates has changed and I have never been able to figure out why, just make modifications to mac mail so that it still does what I want. Issue I'm trying to figure out: When running the script and sending emails Mac mail will now include whatever my default signature is to the end of each email sent. This is fine, but the issue is that in the email summary it defaults to the text of my signature, rather than the text I wrote in my script. Summary being what you see below the subject line in the list of emails usually on the side pane of your email platform before you open the email, usually the first few sentences of the email. So instead of seeing summary of Hi soandso, how are you etc, it instead shows thanks, charlie my contact etc. Of course the work around to this is to use no signature in mac mail and write the signature into the script, but I'd like to figure out why this changed and fix if possible. Thanks!! Here's the script for mac script editor :

```
set {firstName, eAddress} to getData()

tell application "Finder"
set folderPath to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:Send_Mail2:"
set theFile to first file in folderPath as alias
set fileName to name of theFile
end tell

(*tell application "Finder"
set folderPath2 to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:Send_Mail2:"
set theFile2 to second file in folderPath as alias
set fileName2 to name of theFile
end tell


set theAttachment2 to theFile2*)
set theAttachment to theFile

repeat with i from 1 to count firstName
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    (*set theSignature to signature "Standard"*)
    set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"Optical test equipment integration"}
    tell mymail
        make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:item i of eAddress}
        delay 2
        
        (*set message signature to theSignature*)
        set content to "Hi " & item i of firstName & "," & "
```

Hope you've been well since we were last in touch! Checking back to see if you're still working on bla bla bla

```
Test signature"
        
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at after last paragraph
        (*make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment2} at after last paragraph*)
        
    end tell
    --show message window (otherwise it's hidden)
    set visible of mymail to true
    --bring Mail to front
    activate
    send mymail
end tell
end repeat


on getData()
set colA to {}
set colB to {}
tell application "Numbers"
    
    activate
    tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
        #set lastRow to 4
        set lastRow to row count
        #first row index of (get end (last cell of column 1) direction toward the top)
        
        repeat with i from 2 to lastRow
            set end of colA to (value of cell i of column "A")
            set end of colB to (value of cell i of column "B")
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

return {colA, colB}
end getData
```